# How can I create a Spring Roo entity without an identifier field (primary key)

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I am trying to create a Spring Roo entity for a legacy database table. The table does not have a primary key defined.

However, Roo will not let me define an entity without an `identifierField`:

```
@RooEntity(identifierColumn = "", identifierField = "", table = "XYZ", versionField = "")
```

This causes the Roo integration tests to fail with:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
```

Because it creates an `@Id` and `@Column(name = "id")` field in Roo_Entity.aj.

I have tried reverse engineering this table with Roo's DBRE function, but all it does is create an identifier class containing all of the fields of the entity.  When this happens I cannot add finders for the individual table columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Roo requires a primary key and strongly suggests a version identifier.

It's possible to use either a simple or a combined primary key. Also looking at [DBRE documentation](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=base-dbre), there is no mention about tables without primary key.

What about fixing the DB? Which DBMS is it? Is it feasible to add a numeric identifier, possibly auto-generated?

Comment: I really want to avoid modifying the DB schema just so it will work with Roo.  I stil cannot find a way to make Roo work with a table that does not have a primary key, so I will most likely have to add a primary key.

Comment: I never could figure out a way to do it, so I had to modify the table to add a primary key.